# Why C++ libxml2 saves file to 1 line not multiple lines, how to format it better?

Tags: c++, linux, format, line, libxml2

I'm using cygwin and having this code piece:

```
#include<libxml/parser.h>
#include<libxml/tree.h>
#include<libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include<libxml/xpath.h>
#include<libxml/xpathInternals.h>
void main(){
    xmlInitParser();
    xmlDocPtr doc=xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST"1.0");
    xmlNodePtr root=xmlNewNode(NULL,BAD_CAST"root");
    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc,root);
    xmlNewTextChild(root,NULL,BAD_CAST"node01",BAD_CAST"content01");
    xmlNewTextChild(root,NULL,BAD_CAST"node02",BAD_CAST"content02");
    xmlNewTextChild(root,NULL,BAD_CAST"node03",BAD_CAST"content03");
    xmlNodePtr n=xmlNewNode(NULL,BAD_CAST"node01");
    xmlAddChild(root,n);
    xmlNodePtr t=xmlNewText(BAD_CAST"text01");
    xmlAddChild(n,t);
    xmlNewProp(n,BAD_CAST"myprop",BAD_CAST"yes");
    xmlSaveFile("my01.xml",doc);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}
```

It runs and created "my01.xml" file successfully, but all content is inside one line. How can I generate such a file with multiple lines?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `xmlSaveFormatFile`?

Comment: It works!......